# Passport authentication request route not working only in production mode for Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

Currently I have MERN app with passport included for auth flow. In dev mode, runs smoothe and great. In production mode... major problems that I can't seem to figure out. Im drowning in misery trying to figure out my bug.

Front end: React (create-react-app package)
Back end: Express + node

In my configured development mode, the passport flow works fine as expected. It creates a session and communicates with MongoDB to retrieve or create a user without any problems.

However... when I switch to production mode, my client side has trouble communicating with the server side for the /auth/google passport GET route.

Possible thoughts I had that I am probably wrong on:

1) The client relative link path wasn't accessing the proper route (I switched to production and ran on port 4000 to test) All my redirects and callback routes are created properly to handle on this route.

2) Something wrong with the ordering of middleware on index.js page

Below is my main server file

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
require('dotenv/config')
const compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const router = express.Router()
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
const keys = require('./config/keys')


require('./services')
require('./models/User')
require('./models/Course')
require('./models/Curriculum')
require('./models/Module')
require('./models/Section')
require('./models/Tool')
require('./models/Quiz')
require('./models/BlackboardMemo')
require('./models/LiveClass')
require('./models/Response')
require('./models/StudentWork')



const app = express()


app.use(compression())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieSession({maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000,keys: [keys.cookieKey]}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


mongoose.Promise=global.Promise

if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
  mongoose.connect(keys.mLabUrl)
} else {
  mongoose.connect(keys.mongoDB)
}


require('./services/Mailer')(app)
require('./routes/toolRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/courseRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/curriculumRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/userRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/fileRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/moduleRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/sectionRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/quizRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/liveClassRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/paymentRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/generalRoutes')(app)



if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))
  app.get('/', (req, res)=>res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'client/build/index.html')))
}



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
const server = app.listen(PORT)

require('./sockets')(server)


console.log('Listening on port: '+PORT)
```

Below is my client connect attempt

```
<div>
  <a href="/auth/google" className="altLogin"><i className="fab fa-google padding-sides-10 margin-sides-10 font-40"></i></a>
  <a href="/auth/linkedin" className="altLogin"><i className="fab fa-linkedin-in padding-sides-10 margin-sides-10 font-40"></i></a>
  <a href="/auth/facebook" className="altLogin"><i className="fab fa-facebook-f padding-sides-10 margin-sides-10 font-40"></i></a>
</div>
```

And my route snippet

```
app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google',{scope: ['profile','email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],accessType: 'offline', approvalPrompt: 'force'}))
      app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google'),(req,res)=>res.redirect('/'))
```

Any help, insight or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an update to make... It seems to happens when I update my SSL cert. Could this be a CORS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, it was a scoping issue. The current parameters did not line up with what information I was looking to request. Solved

Comment: Can you share more on what the issue was please ? What do you mean Scoping issue ?